# Как сократить повторящиюйся код с PyQt5?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, pyside2, qlayout

У меня в программе имеется функция, которая создает шесть зон и добавляет в каждую зону по одному виджету, но вот кода у меня много и он повторяющийся.

Можете, пожалуйста, помочь с исправлением? Пробовал работать с `eval` и циклом, но там ошибка возникает.

Вот собственно код *Python* (это всё в функции):

```
import sys
from Plates.FirstProgram.FormBuilder import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, \
    QGridLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon, QPixmap

class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.create_all_forms()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_all_forms(self):
        self.image_area = QLabel(self)
        self.general_image = QPixmap('Images/settings_image.png')
        self.image_area.setPixmap(self.general_image)

        self.text_width_size = QLabel(self)
        self.text_width_size.setText('Enter width of array.')

        self.text_height_size = QLabel(self)
        self.text_height_size.setText('Enter height of array.')

        self.textbox_for_width = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox_for_height = QLineEdit(self)

        self.create_button = QPushButton("Create")

    def create_layers(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        zero_image_layer = QHBoxLayout() # вот здесь начало
        zero_image_layer.addWidget(self.image_area)
        layout.addLayout(zero_image_layer)

        first_layer = QHBoxLayout()
        first_layer.addWidget(self.text_width_size)
        layout.addLayout(first_layer)

        second_layer = QHBoxLayout()
        second_layer.addWidget(self.textbox_for_width)
        layout.addLayout(second_layer)

        third_layer = QHBoxLayout()
        third_layer.addWidget(self.text_height_size)
        layout.addLayout(third_layer)

        forth_layer = QHBoxLayout()
        forth_layer.addWidget(self.textbox_for_height)
        layout.addLayout(forth_layer)

        fifth_layer = QHBoxLayout()
        fifth_layer.addWidget(self.create_button)
        layout.addLayout(fifth_layer) # и здесь конец

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        self.create_and_connect_grid()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.setFixedSize(250, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('Plates')

    def create_and_connect_grid(self):
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.formBuilder = FormBuilder()
        self.grid.addWidget(self.formBuilder, 0, 0, Qt.AlignBottom)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick, извините, исправил. Только там нужна фотография одна для картинки на главном меню.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @S. Nick, В общем, в первом классе есть функция 'create_layers', в которой очень много повторяющегося кода. Просто я вроде бы даже у Вас видел, как Вы строили формы с помощью цикла 'for', но я не знаю, как это можно сделать у меня. То-есть, если кратко, то нужно заменить повторяющийся код в функции на более короткий код.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

я не понял о каких `eval` и `циклах` вы говорите. А заменить код в функции на более короткий код можно так:

```
import sys
#? from Plates.FirstProgram.FormBuilder import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, \
    QGridLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, \
    QLineEdit, QFormLayout 
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon, QPixmap


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.create_all_forms()
        self.create_layers()

    def create_all_forms(self):
        self.image_area = QLabel(self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.general_image = QPixmap('lena-2.png').scaled(                  # Images/settings_image.png
            250, 250, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation
        )
        self.image_area.setPixmap(self.general_image)

        self.text_width_size = QLabel(self)
        self.text_width_size.setText('Введите ширину массива.')

        self.text_height_size = QLabel(self)
        self.text_height_size.setText('Введите высоту массива.')

        self.textbox_for_width = QLineEdit()
        self.textbox_for_height = QLineEdit()

        self.create_button = QPushButton("Создать")

    def create_layers(self):                                              # !!!
        layout = QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow(self.image_area)
        layout.addRow(self.text_width_size, self.textbox_for_width)
        layout.addRow(self.text_height_size, self.textbox_for_height)
        layout.addRow(self.create_button)
    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        self.create_and_connect_grid()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
#?        self.setFixedSize(250, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('Plates')

    def create_and_connect_grid(self):
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.formBuilder = FormBuilder()
        self.grid.addWidget(self.formBuilder, 0, 0, Qt.AlignBottom)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте, еще раз :). Скажите, пожалуйста, а как можно с помощью метода 'addRow()' добавить три кнопки? Получается добавить в ряд максимум только две формы, не более.

Comment: @GunTHE задайте новый вопрос. Покажите что у вас есть, расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.